# ImportError at / No module named response with django appengine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am trying to run django project with appengine . It is running properly on localhost. But when I tried to upload it to appspot.com it is giving me the following error

```
ImportError at /
No module named response
```

Here is [traceback](http://pastebin.com/D93G9MH7).

views.py

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello World")
```

app.yaml

```
application: demoapptotest
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:

- url: /.*
  script: main.application

libraries:

- name: django
  version: latest
- name: PIL
  version: latest

env_variables:
  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: 'app1.settings'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do `from django.http import HttpResponse`.

Comment: Thanks , Can you please tell me what was the problem with `from django.http.response import HttpResponse` ?